# What does * beside some steps in explain plan in oracle mean?

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

3 tables: employees(emp_id, dept_id, job_id, emp_fname, emp_lname, salary, address, email), departments(dept_id,d_name) and jobs(job_id,j_title).

non-unique indexes on employees(emp_id), departments(dept_id) and jobs(job_id).

```
SQL> explain plan for 
select d.d_name, j.j_title, count(1) 
from employees e join departments d on e.dept_id=d.dept_id
join jobs j on e.job_id=j.job_id
where e.salary>30000 
group by d.d_name, j.j_title;

SQL>select * from table(DBMS_XPLAN.display);

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

| Id | Operation | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time |

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT | | 10 | 890 | 4 (25)| 00:00:01 |
| 1 |   HASH GROUP BY | | 10 | 890 | 4 (25)| 00:00:01 |
| 2 |     NESTED LOOPS | | | | | |
| 3 |       NESTED LOOPS | | 10 | 890 | 3 (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 4 |         NESTED LOOPS | | 10 | 640 | 3 (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 5 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL | EMPLOYEES | 10 | 390 | 3 (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 6 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| JOBS | 1 | 25 | 0 (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 7 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN | JOBS_JOB_ID | 1 | | 0 (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 8 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN | DEPT_DEPT_ID | 1 | | 0 (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 9 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | DEPARTMENTS | 1 | 25 | 0 (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
    ---------------------------------------------------

```
5 - filter("E"."SALARY">30000)

7 - access("E"."JOB_ID"="J"."JOB_ID")

8 - access("E"."DEPT_ID"="D"."DEPT_ID")

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

1. What does * with step 5,7 and 9 mean?
2. What is the role of 3 nested loops here?
3. Steps 7 and 6 are in the same loop. Why are steps 8 and 9 in different loops when they're doing a similar job?
4. Can anyone please explain me what each step is doing?

Comment: These refer to additional optimiser notes about those steps that should have appeared below the plan.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? @JeffreyKemp

Comment: You have not copied the entire explain plan into your question. Edit your question to supply the missing info and maybe we can help you.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Done. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

As Jeffrey mentioned, these are some additional information about the execution plan. They usually appear for `where`/`like` (etc) conditions and for `HASH JOINS` (may be other but I am not sure). Basically where-ever optimizer wants you to give extra information which couldn't be put in the output of explain plan.

You can replicate it yourself by running below.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
your_query;
```

Then run

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
```

Output (In my case)

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |                |    17 |   187 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| EMP_DATA_ENAME |    17 |   187 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("ENAME" LIKE 'ZM%')
       filter("ENAME" LIKE 'ZM%')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
| 4 |         NESTED LOOPS | | 10 | 640 | 3 (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 5 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL | EMPLOYEES | 10 | 390 | 3 (0)| 00:00:01 |
5 - filter("E"."SALARY">30000)
```

All rows in the `EMPLOYEES` table will be queried, and those matching the given filter on `SALARY` will be sent to the next step in the plan.

```
| 6 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| JOBS | 1 | 25 | 0 (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 7 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN | JOBS_JOB_ID | 1 | | 0 (0)| 00:00:01 |
7 - access("E"."JOB_ID"="J"."JOB_ID")
```

Each row that is emitted from step 5 includes the `JOB_ID` for the employee. The index `JOBS_JOB_ID` will be probed (step 7) for this `JOB_ID`, and the ROWID will be used to retrieve the corresponding row from the `JOBS` table (step 6).

```
| 3 |       NESTED LOOPS | | 10 | 890 | 3 (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 8 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN | DEPT_DEPT_ID | 1 | | 0 (0)| 00:00:01 |
8 - access("E"."DEPT_ID"="D"."DEPT_ID")
```

The `DEPT_ID` from the `EMPLOYEES` table (previously retrieved in step 5) is now used to probe the `DEPT_DEPT_ID` index (step 8).

```
| 2 |     NESTED LOOPS | | | | | |
| 9 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | DEPARTMENTS | 1 | 25 | 0 (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

The ROWID from the `DEPT_DEPT_ID` index is now used to retrieve the row from the DEPARTMENTS table.

```
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT | | 10 | 890 | 4 (25)| 00:00:01 |
| 1 |   HASH GROUP BY | | 10 | 890 | 4 (25)| 00:00:01 |
```

The results are put into a hash table (using a key based on `d.d_name`+`j.j_title`), counting each record as it goes. When the last record has been retrieved, the hash table is scanned to return the counts for each d_name,j_title.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) 
Can you also tell me that, steps 7 and 6 are in the same loop. Why are steps 8 and 9 in different loops when they're doing a similar job?

Comment: No particular reason - explain plan is just a debug output from the optimiser, and has its quirks. You can sometimes get slightly different patterns from similar execution plans.